# javascript return result ajax request by self functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, return

Guys!

I have a one misunderstanding in javascript. I want make a ajax-request with function foo() and i want return result data by foo() return, but i can't return something in callback function in $.ajax.

So i want this: if ajax reurn data then function foo() return same data.

```
function foo(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        param: {} 
     }).done(function(data) {
          //I need return data variable how result of function foo() running            
     });
    return data; // if data was complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
function foo(){
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    param: {} 
 }).done(function(data) {
      return data;        
 });
}
```

Comment: Yes, i try this before. but if i use like  var bar = foo() the bar = undefined, because this return data for function(data){} it is other namespace :(

Comment: Are you getting data value from Ajax call?